# Is it possible to focus on different (but related) features on the same Atlas page?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I have a map showing a city and its divisons. I have then several features in other layer with the style set to show only the feature designed by the atlas by $id = $atlasid

So far so good. Then I want to create a print composer with two maps: the first one will be set to be "controled by atlas" with 10% margin around it (this I know how to do). Then the second one need to show the same feature but need to be centered by the city division that it belongs to. In other wors I need to input a formula that says whitch layer that map need to use to center the image. (like in the image)

[image]

Any ideas, Plugins or solutions?

Comment: Not a perfect solution but as a start you could create an overview (create new map, set overview of the other map in the properties with an appropriate scale) and select center on overview. That should work not too badly, although it will center on the view rather than on the city division.     Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding columns to your coverage layer for overview_min_x, overview_min_y, overview_max_x, overview_map_y and prepopulating them with the desired extents for each feature for this secondary map. Then you can use data defined overrides for the secondary map extents and bind them to these columns.