# QGIS Atlas generation - 2 panels with different sections both Atlas generated

Tags: qgis, filter, atlas

I have a polyline that I split in 5000 m sections and I made it to generate an Atlas for the first step, but since the sections that I want to show are long and not wide I would like to add sections, e.g. Atlas Map page1 shows section 1 and 2 (instead of the same green section1, the second panel should show orange section2. [image: see picture with the 2 panels:] 
I tested filtering the Atlas, but I got stuck and wasnt sucessfull. I created 2 virtual layers containing every second section, but after I added the second panel I could not find out if it is possible to let the panels be controlled by different layers for  Atlas generation. Any idea how to get 2 panels with continuing  sections?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207055/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-different-but-related-features-on-the-same-atlas-pa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like here:

1. Add xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax to each feature of your atlas layer. Your can do it with the function:

`xmax($geometry)`

[image]

2. Control your atlas by extentension, defining a functions inside thouse xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax in composer (here, as you can figure it out, that -0.002 creates an small margin around the feature):

`attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id',  @atlas_featurenumber +1) , 'xmin') -0.002`

[image]

If you use this system don't mark "controlled by atlas".

Be creative and you will get a perfect atlas.

Edit:

HOW TO EDIT EXTENSION BY ATRIBUTE IN COMPOSER

Select the square of map --> properties --> extension --> xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax: edit... (sorry, my QGIS is in spanish, but can get the position):

[image]

If you write the function properly you will get the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax value of the desired feature of your atlas:

[image]

Same for each xy of square 2:
Here "+1" means "go to the following feature from your atlas layer". Do the same for each xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax and adapt the function.

[image]

Update to avoid repeated features:

Here is the code for the upper map xmin:

```
case
when @atlas_featurenumber = 1 then  attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 1),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 2 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 3),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 3 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 5),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 4 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 7),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 5 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 9),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 6 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 11),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 7 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 13),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 8 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 15),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 9 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 17),'xmin')
when @atlas_featurenumber = 10 then attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id', 19),'xmin')
end
```

This code allows you to go from feature 1 to 3 to 5... in the upper square. Do the same for xmax/ymin/ymax. Then copy the code, go to lower map and paste it replacing those 1,3,5... by 2,4,6...
As you may have noticed this code allows you to create a consequent map with 10 pages as much. If it has more page, you just need to add lines with the same logic.
[image]

And if you have odd number of segments you can make invisible the lower map by, also, adding a function to make it transparent like (when Atlas feature is null then make it 100% transparent):
[image]

Comment: I was in the process of writing the exact same answer, you beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry mate. Anyway, post your answer if you find a finest path to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot César, that sounds brilliant, but I have problems to follow, sorry. Step1 is clear. I added xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax in my Attribute table. but step2...."Control your atlas by extentension" here I am a little bit puzzled. In my Atlas generation tab I still choose my layer for generating the atlas, right? underneath it I could check "filter" or "sort" is this on of the windows where I input "attribute (get_feature( 'Atlas', 'id',  @atlas_featurenumber +1) , 'xmin') -0.002"? No, right? I am not sure where I put this.

Comment: I hope now you repeat the process for each extension coords and map square. Regards.

Comment: And one last thing: that that -0.002 is arbitrary and It will depend on your CRS. Adapt it to your data and remember for: xmin and ymin use -, for xmax and ymax use +. That's the way to make the margin properly. Regards.

Comment: Perfect. It works now roughly. First it did not, because I also told the map to rotate according to an attribute.  I just start understand the single expressions in the expression string you gave (sorry this is quite new for me). So I added in Map rotation that it should also take the next rotation angle. Also I had some trouble with scale first. All solved. Thanks again for all your effort, I would have never get these ideas on my own. Altas page 1 is  perfekt showing section 1 and 2, but on page 2 is currently section2 and 3. I dont want duplicates. Here section 3 and 4 should shown.